# How do you apply textures and colors?

Tags: texturing

I'm finding that the more I use Blender the harder it is. I'd just like to know how to apply a texture or surface to an object. I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: You need to specify the version of blender you are using, and the render type

Comment: *"how to apply a texture or surface to an object"* what do you mean? Any screenshots of what you'd like to get and what you have so far?

Comment: Why does render type need to be specified? Any render type... lol. I just want to give an object a color, texture etc..... V2.79b

Comment: I keep having to quit blender before I can render anything. I can't get the menus to stop disappearing!

Comment: To get it better, video tutorials will be an option... You can get a lot of tutorials that includes both versions at YouTube

Comment: [This](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) might be helpful, if you want to know how to brush up your question so it's not too broad.